# HttpContext.Current.Handler is null during PostMapRequestHandler for static files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am writing a http module to apply some cache settings depending on the type of request we are serving, and the code I need to run looks something like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Handler.FullName == "System.Web.StaticFileHandler" &&
    CacheBustedResourceRegex.IsMatch(request.RawUrl))
{
    _log.DebugFormat("Explicitly allow caching on '{0}'. Max age is {1}",
        request.RawUrl,
        MaxAgeForCacheBustedResources);
    response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    response.Cache.SetMaxAge(MaxAgeForCacheBustedResources);
}
```

However, HttpContext.Current.Handler is always null for static files.  It is null in PostMapRequestHandler, PreRequestHandlerExecute, PostRequestHandlerExecute and events.  An example URL for which it is null is `/stylesheet/welcome.css?63577391827`.

Using aspnet 4.5 / IIS 8.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why you exect there to be "System.Web.StaticFileHandler" ? Why it is not enough to check only CacheBustedResourceRegex.IsMatch(request.RawUrl) ?

Comment: CacheBustedResourceRegex is a little too inclusive:  `\.\w+\?\d+$`  It matches anything that has an extension and a query string that consists of digits.  I was hoping to check whether or not StaticFileHandler was being used to serve the request in order to avoid having a white-list of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.StaticFileHandler served static content request in classic IIS mode. Most probably you are using integrated IIS mode, where static content is processed by native module StaticFileModule and thus Handler is null
To solve your question there are 2 options:

1. Swtich to old classic mode. But you will loose in performance
2. Use integrated mode and detect static content by yourself.